# Как можно добавлять разные экземпляры структуры в функцию?

Tags: c

Есть у меня экземпляр структуры вида:

```
typedef struct{
const char     str[32];          // текстовая надпись
const char     numberButton[4];  // номер кнопки
const uint32_t size;             // размер кнопки
const uint32_t y;                //  положение y координата
const uint32_t x;                // положение x координата
const uint32_t TextcolF;         // цвет надписи
const uint32_t TextcolB;         // цвет фона
const uint32_t NumColF;          // цвет цифр
const uint32_t NumColB;          // цвет цифр
} const _TypeButonPressedOn;
```

Я делаю определение структуры:

```
const _TypeButonPressedOn ReadButton; 
const _TypeButonPressedOn DellButton; // и так далее
```

Где ReadButton - это экземпляр кнопки.

Вывожу кнопку на экран кнопку с помощью функции вида:

```
    void ButtonReadOn(void)
{
    moveM(ReadButton.y,ReadButton.x);
    colorM_F(ReadButton.TextcolF);
    colorM_B(ReadButton.TextcolB);
    addstrMenu(ReadButton.str);
    writeWindow(ReadButton.y, ReadButton.x, ReadButton.TextcolF, ReadButton.TextcolB, (char*)ReadButton.str, ReadButton.size);
}
```

И таких функций может быть десятки штук.

Как можно сделать замену 'ReadButton' в функции 'ButtonReadOn' для упрощения работы? Создал я другую кнопку и чтобы не переделывать 'ReadButton' на 'DellButton' в каждой строчки, прописать 'DellButton' и чтобы компилятор сам заменил 'ReadButton' на 'DellButton'.

Comment: а передать кнопку как параметр функции? или так не пойдет? `void ButtonOn(const _TypeButonPressedOn* btn) {moveM(btn->y,btn->x); ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В си шаблоны пишутся с помощью макросов.

```
# define TEMPLATE_BUTTONS_FUNC( FUNC_NAME , VAR_NAME ) \
  void FUNC_NAME ( void ) { \
    moveM(VAR_NAME.y,VAR_NAME.x); \
    colorM_F(VAR_NAME.TextcolF); \
    colorM_B(VAR_NAME.TextcolB); \
    addstrMenu(VAR_NAME.str); \
    writeWindow(VAR_NAME.y, VAR_NAME.x, VAR_NAME.TextcolF, \
      VAR_NAME.TextcolB, (char*)VAR_NAME.str, VAR_NAME.size); \
    }

TEMPLATE_BUTTONS_FUNC ( ButtonReadOn , ReadButton )
TEMPLATE_BUTTONS_FUNC ( ButtonDellOn , DellButton )
```